# How to use a UITableView section index as an NSInteger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set the `kJTCalendarDaySelected` of my [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar) to be equal to the `index.section` that is visible. If the index is 0, I want `kJTCalendarDaySelected` set to 1 (1st of the month), if the index is 1, I want it set to 2 (2nd of the month), and so on.

When I try to do this like so:

```
-(BOOL)whatSectionsAreVisible {
    NSArray *visibleRowIndexes = [self.agendaTable indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *index in visibleRowIndexes) {

        self.daySection = index.section;

        // Update views
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kJTCalendarDaySelected" object:self.daySection];

        // Store currentDateSelected
        [self.calendar setCurrentDateSelected:self.daySection];

        NSLog(@"The visible section has an index of: %ld", (long)index.section);

        if (index.section == 0) {
            NSLog(@"index.row is indeed 0");
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I get the following error:

`implicit conversion of non-Objective-c pointer type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC`
[image]

How can I convert index.section's id to an NSInteger that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: use `NSNumber *indexNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.daySection]` and pass `indexNumber` in notification object. An you can conert it to integer by `NSInteger daySectionIndex = [indexNumber integerValue]` .

Comment: To answer the question in the title: the section index ***is*** an `NSInteger`, and is ***not*** a pointer-to-an-object. The `postNotification` method requires a pointer, and evidently your `setCurrentDateSelected` method also requires a pointer. What is unclear from your question is what type of object the notification observer, and the `setCurrentDateSelected` method expect.

Comment: ...or you can use modern boxing syntax: `...object:@(self.daySection)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code which remove your errors

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kJTCalendarDaySelected" object:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.daySection]];

NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *selecteDate = [[formatter standaloneMonthSymbols] objectAtIndex:[formatter dateFromString:strDate]];

NSLog(@"%@",selectedDate);
```

Here selectedDate will be in the form of month name if your indexpath.section is "0" then it will give you 'January' so you can set month name in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass parameter type id.
suppose you can use in this way..

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.daySection],@"sectionIndex", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kJTCalendarDaySelected" object:dict];
```

Hope this will help you...